# Vue 2 Coverage issue : Getting different behaviour for vue 2 and vue 3

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I have setup unit testing using installation instructions from https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/

Tests are running properly. But the coverage is coming incorrectly.

It's not showing coverage for all the lines. It shows coverage in the first line and doesn't show coverage anywhere else. Don't know what's the issue is here.

This is not working with Vue 2. But with Vue 3 its working.

Package:
{
"name": "vue_three_without_ts",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
"build": "vue-cli-service build",
"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
"lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"core-js": "^3.8.3",
"vue": "^3.2.13"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
"@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
"babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
"jest": "^27.0.5"
}
}

[Vue3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UiOd.png)

package:
{
"name": "vue_two_without_ts",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
"build": "vue-cli-service build",
"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
"lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"core-js": "^3.8.3",
"vue": "^2.6.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
"@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
"@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
"babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
"jest": "^27.0.5",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
}
}

[Vue2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Hsn.png)

Comment: Both the testcase are same.

Comment: Vue 3 its showing 50% for function which is correct since I have commented my testcase from test suit for the component. But for the vue 2 its showing 100%, which is not correct.